# MySQL: ON DUPLICATE KEY statement fails in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sql-insert

I'm trying to run an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY statement with jdbc and it just fails with no error message as to why. Even when I run the statement individually in Script.sql, it doesn't work. Here is the statement I'm trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO ptable(username, p, roll, joined) 
           VALUES ('username', 0, 0, 1) 
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE joined=VALUES(1);
```

Basically, I only want to insert a new row if username doesn't exist and if it does then I want to change the joined column in their row to 1. My username column is set to both the PRIMARY KEY and a UNIQUE KEY.

Comment: could you post table structure ? and what is `joined` ? is it a column name ?

Comment: why your question tag with mysql and sql-server?? Can you update your question with only one database which on you facing this issue.5

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), it should be `joined=1`

Comment: The column's data type for joined is BIT.

Answer (score 2):

the `values(col_name)` function accept a column name as an argument when it used with `ON DUPLICATE KEYS`, and you are passing an integer. I think you need to try something like this:

```
    INSERT INTO ptable(username, p, roll, joined) 
           VALUES ('username', 0, 0, 1) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE joined = 1;
```

for more info check its documentation [dev.mysql.com/doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Yes. `VALUES(1)` means the value of the `1` column, which doesn't exist. `1` means the value of one.

Comment: Or `VALUES(joined)`